# Why is my program printing the memory address instead of the value I'm passing through named pipe?

Tags: c, parent-child, named-pipes

I'm having trouble sending values from my named pipe to the parent and child processes. I inserted a value, 22, just to test it and I keep getting what looks like the address of the integer.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void fib(int n) {
  int fib1;
  int fib2;
  int fd;
  int sum;

  char * myfifo = "/home/user/Desktop";
  mkfifo("myfifo", 0666);

  if (mkfifo("myfifo", 0666) < 0 && errno != EEXIST) {
    perror("mkfifo failure");
    exit(1);
  }

  if ((fd = open("myfifo", O_WRONLY)) < 0) {
    perror("open failure");
    exit(2);
  }

  if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
    fib1 = 22;

    write(fd, &fib1, sizeof(fib1)); // write fib(n) into the pipe/shared memory/shared queue

    close(fd);
    return;
  } else {
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
      // child
      fib(n - 1);
      exit(0);
    } else {
      waitpid(pid, NULL, 0); // parent
      fib(n - 2);
      read(fd, &fib1, sizeof(fib1)); // read fib(n - 1) & fib(n - 2) from the pipe/shared memory/shared queue
      read(fd, &fib2, sizeof(fib2)); // read fib(n - 1) & fib(n - 2) from the pipe/shared memory/shared queue
      printf("Value 1: %d\n", fib1);
      printf("Value 2: %d\n", fib2);
      sum = fib1 + fib2;
      printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
      write(fd, &sum, sizeof(sum)); // write fib(n) back into the pipe/shared memory/shared queue

    }

    return;
  }
  printf("Sum: %d", sum);
}

int main() {
  int value;
  printf("Enter number to be calculated: ");
  scanf("%d", &value);
  fib(value);
  return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
Enter number to be calculated: 3
Value 1: -140833897
Value 2: 0
Sum: -140833897
Value 1: 0
Value 2: 0
Sum: 0
```

Comment: `fd` is never set. Also, the code is incomplete. At a minimum we need the `main`. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @Michael, What  are the retrun values form the `read()` calls?

Comment: @Michael, `fd` remains unassigned.  Save time, enable all complier warnings.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for pointing that out - added my main.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica What do you mean? Also, I did initially setup my fd assignments but found that the code would only ask for the input and then nothing would happen.

Comment: "*but found that the code would only ask for the input and then nothing would happen*". But removing the fd assignment clearly won't work. Why would you think it is ok to use a value that is never set? You can't attempt to fix one problem by introducing another problem.

Comment: @Michael 1) Better to post that better code with the `fd` assignment.  As is, passing an uninitialized `fd` to `write()` is pointless. 2) `int read(..)` returns a value.  What values were returned in the `read()` calls?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I tried to pass the value 22 to read(fd, &fib1, sizeof(fib1)) but it gave me -140833897

Comment: @Michael,  `char * myfifo = "/home/user/Desktop";  mkfifo("myfifo", 0666);` is suspicious.  Perhaps you want `char * myfifo = "/home/user/Desktop";  fd = mkfifo("myfifo", 0666);`? I'd recommended to follow that with a `printf("fd=%d\n", fd);`

Comment: @Michael "but it gave me -140833897"  --> are you saying the return of `read()` was  -140833897 like as in `int retval = read(fd, &fib1, sizeof(fib1)); printf("%d\n", retval);` or something else?  Hmm, I see now you think `fib1` is the return value.  It is not.  The return value is from `int revval = read(.....)`.  It indicate an error or how many bytes were read.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica When I do `read(fd, &fib1, sizeof(fib1); printf('%d\n", fib1);`, I get -140833897 but then I use `int retval = read(fd, &fib1, sizeof(fib1)); printf("%d\n", retval);` I get -1

Comment: @Michael That -1 means `read()` errored and the value in `fib1` was not certainly filled.  Likely the same value as before the `read()`.  You need to determine why `read()` failed.  I suspect the value of `fd` is junk.